# Switching from POP3 to IMAP, to use mail on multiple devices - a good idea?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, android, imap, pop3

I've been using an email account for a few years, using POP3/Outlook(2010 now).

Recently, I've started using email more and more on my mobile devices (Android phone, iPad). For now, they are set to use POP3, the same as my main email client - Outlook on my laptop.

I am looking for a solution/configuration that would allow me to have access to all the email in my Inbox and Sent Items **on my phone** (the same as in Outlook) - ideally when offline, but when online only would be ok too.

I was thinking of switching to IMAP on all devices, but it's not clear to me if I'll be able to access email online/offline in my Outlook the same way after the switch

Can you please share some thoughts on what would be the best way to make this scenario happen: access all my sent/received emails from my Android phone, while I can still do the same thing from my Outlook/laptop.

Comment: IMAP will work. However, your question is too open-ended in its current form and will likely be closed. If you can edit it to ask a specific question (see the [FAQ]), that will help you get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You create a local copy of all devices with IMAP. This means, what ever is on your server is duplicated on all devices (depending on the settings of each device).

I run my own mail server. I have web access, I use Outlook 2010 (IMAP) and my Android phone. I send from my mobile, it appears in my sent items on my Outlook and web mail.

Emails are free and easy. If you're worried, I suggest you create a new account with Gmail (or similar) and set it up on your phone and Outlook and test it before moving.

The only thing I will say though is, how much storage on your phone is up to your phone. If you have 1GB in your inbox and 2 GB in your sent items I would assume your mobile device may struggle and automatically only load 100mb (or whatever the threshold is).